# How to call wsdl service using soap client in php

Tags: php, soap-client

I am new in WSDL service.I do not know to call it using soap client in PHP. Please guide me.My wsdl is

```
POST /WSElectronicOrder/ElectronicOrder.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: api.ekeystone.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://eKeystone.com/CheckInventory"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckInventory xmlns="http://eKeystone.com">
      <Key>string</Key>
      <FullAccountNo>string</FullAccountNo>
      <FullPartNo>string</FullPartNo>
    </CheckInventory>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate a client code using [wsdl2phpgenerator](https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator)